# Intellij Darcula Theme Revert

Tags: intellij-idea

I have IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 14.1.5, and I was wondering how to change the theme from Darcula to a white theme. When I first installed and downloaded IntelliJ, I chose Darcula, but I am not sure how to change it back.

Comment: Not really a programming question..

Comment: @RaGe  Just where would this question go ..

Comment: Beats me, so I didn't flag, answered it instead. [Superuser](http://superuser.com/) maybe?

Comment: @RaGe  I think you did fine to answer the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to: <kbd>File</kbd> -> <kbd>Settings</kbd>

or alternatively, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>:

[image]